# stopped httpd but localhost still bind to 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: apache, homebrew

I use brew to install `httpd`, I stopped the service using `brew services stop httpd` then I visit locahost, I still can see apache is running?

Comment: Can you try using: `sudo netstat -lp | grep 80` this will show you the PID of the process that has the port bound. If this is not apache, kill it. If this is apache, kill it ;) Try using `sudo apachectl stop`, or just `kill -9 <thePID>`

Comment: Check if the service is running: `pgrep -fl httpd`. If it is probably is stuck. Try killing the instance with: `pkill -f  httpd` or  `pkill -f  apache2`. If those don't work, try  `kill -9 <PID>` (You'll obtain the PID of the process from the first command).

Comment: @MattClark netstat: option requires an argument -- p

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz I got bunch of these `97 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
276 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
902 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
903 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
904 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
2009 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND` What are they? are they started themselves?

Comment: @Melissa92,  you have several instances of the process running (probably parent and childs) try kill each of them until there's no one.

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz I killed httpd, but they appear again when I run `pgrep -fl httpd `

Comment: Ugh, of course OSX has to be different then every other OS in existence.... How about this one? `netstat -anv`

Comment: @Melissa92 you must kill all the instances (parent and childs).

Comment: `killall httpd`, did you try running `sudo apachectl stop`?

Comment: If you see many children, use `ps aux | grep httpd` to see a list of all running httpd processes, Run `kill -9 <thePID>` on the lowest number from the previous output.

Comment: what is the pid for my result? https://pastebin.com/ZAxvFSay `I run ps aux | grep httpd`

Comment: @Melissa92 It should be then `kill  -9 3110` and `kill -9 3109` You have two instances running, one with root (probably you used sudo) and the other one with www user.

Comment: another port appear after the kill

Comment: @Melissa92 attach the output of  `ps aux | grep httpd` after killing the processes o

Comment: _www              3356   0.0  0.0  2455088    704   ??  S     9:25AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root              3355   0.0  0.0  2455344   3588   ??  Ss    9:25AM   0:00.14 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
private.laptop     3967   0.0  0.0  2444068    816 s004  S+    9:46AM   0:00.00 grep httpd

Comment: @Melissa92 I've elaborated an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give following command:    `service httpd stop`

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: `brew` doesn't give you a clue? OSX.

Comment: I didn't think about it. Then try /usr/sbin/apachectl stop

Answer (score 0):

You must kill the processes. As I can see from your comment you are running `httpd` as the users  `www` and `root`:

```
_www 3356 0.0 0.0 2455088 704 ?? S 9:25AM 0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND 
root 3355 0.0 0.0 2455344 3588 ?? Ss 9:25AM 0:00.14 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND 
private.laptop 3967 0.0 0.0 2444068 816 s004 S+ 9:46AM 0:00.00 grep httpd
```

The first column represent the `user` and the second column the process ID or `PID`.

Try running:

```
sudo kill -9 3356
sudo kill -9 3355
```

After each execution verify the services dissapear using `ps aux | grep httpd`

The last proccess `private.laptop` isn't related to your problem so no need to kill it.

If your problem isn't solved by this, maybe a daemon is executing your httpd, please [refeer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309814/killing-an-unknown-self-restarting-server-on-port-80-mac-osx).

Comment: I got this after killing

_www              4018   0.0  0.0  2455088    720   ??  S     9:53AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root              4017   0.0  0.0  2455344   3580   ??  Ss    9:53AM   0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND

Comment: It will reappear after the killing.

Comment: @Melissa92 yes, probably a daemon auto starting your httpd, please check the updated answer.